# No Wi-Fi connections to see ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: wireless

I just installed ubuntu 16.04.1 on my parents their old computer
And if I want to connect to the internet, I get no connections to see

When I want to see if Broadcom Corporation is enabled it isn't in the list

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers